# Why Riemann distance better for PSD matrices than Euclidian distance?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can you explain to me why Riemann distance is better for positive semidefinite matrices (for example covariance matrices) than Euclidian distance?

Here is the riemannian distance:
$$
d\left(Σ_A,Σ_B\right)=\sqrt{ \sum_i{\ln^2⁡{λ_i (Σ_A,Σ_B)}}}
$$
Where $$\lambda_i(Σ_A,Σ_B)$$ is the generalized eigeinvalue of A and B (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem).

[image]

I do not have, or little knowledge in geodesics but it seems to be the reason why it is better.

Any clarification would be very helpful

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is like comparing the distance function on $\mathbb{S}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ given by measuring distance along the sphere (i.e. the Riemann distance) and measuring distance as points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (analogous to Euclidean distance). Intuitively, distance in $\mathbb{S}^2$ is the "better" notion of distance because it measures distance within the space $\mathbb{S}^2$ (i.e. an intrinsic description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see several advantages of Riemann distance over Euclidean distance for covariance matrix.

First, Riemann distance is scaling free. if you change unit for both $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_B$, you would expect the similarity should keep unchanged. i.e., $$d(\Sigma_A, \Sigma_B) = d(k\Sigma_A, k\Sigma_B) $$, which is not true for Euclidean distance.

Second, you would expect different impacts for discrepancies among diagonal elements vs. among off-diagonal elements, which is not true for Euclidean distance either.

Third, Riemann distance respects the positive semidefinite constraints. Considering the example that $\Sigma_A - dA$ is semidefinite while $\Sigma_A + dA$ is not, you would not expect they both have the same distance to $\Sigma_A$, which is the case of Euclidean distance.